# MVC4: how to set session variable to null in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, razor

I am using MVC session variable in Razor view javascript. But if I want set that session value to null how to do that?

```
 function UpdateMembershipJavascriptObject() {
        var tempMembership = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Session["Membership"]));
        if (tempMembership) {

            membershipData.updateMembership(tempMembership);
            updateSubtotal();     
            //here I set to null
        }
    }
```

I tried `'@Session["Membership"]' = null` but getting error on `= null` on the browser.

Comment: Is session the correct choice? If you want to read back once in the same request and then have the session item removed you can use TempData instead which is cleared at the end of the request.

Comment: Using Session State directly is a bad practice in ASP.Net MVC. What kind of information do you want to store?

Answer (score 1):

Session variables are a server side thing. Your javascript code executes on client side browser. So you cannot set a server side variable from your javascript code directly.

What you can do is, make an ajax call to a server action method and update the session value there.

```
if (tempMembership) {

        membershipData.updateMembership(tempMembership);
        updateSubtotal();     

        $.post("@Url.Action("SetSession","Home")",function(){
               //done. Do something else
        });
}
```

Assuming you have a `SetSession` action method in your `HomeController`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SetSession()
{
   Session["Membership"]=null;
   return Json(new { status="success"});
}
```